# Sources for sets of exercises

Tags: education

I'm a young math teacher who often deals with the problem of finding good sources of sets of exercises as inspiration for my own exercises sheets and exams. In the past I frequently visited ixl.com (example: [Grad 9 maths practice](https://eu.ixl.com/math/grade-9)) but are there better options? What sources (web, books...) do you like/use? I'm interested in finding as many types of problems to a specific topic as possible.

**Example (Different types of problem to the topic "fractions")**

- addition of fractions
- subtraction of fractions
- division of fractions
- multiplication of fractions

To be even more specific you could divide the skills mentioned above in something like "addition of algebraic fractions" and "addition of fractions with variables" and something like that.